# Error in set_email handler: start_monitoring() missing 1 required positional argument: 'message'

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Programming assistance with the following error:

```
def start_monitoring(recipient_email,message):
    try:
        global monitoring_flag
        monitoring_flag = True

        while monitoring_flag:
            # Perform monitoring tasks
            current_location = retrieve_truck_location()  # Retrieve the current GPS location of the truck
            truck_status = check_truck_status()  # Check the status of the truck using external APIs or GPS tracking services

            # Send updates based on contact info (email or phone)
            if recipient_email:
                send_email(recipient_email,message)
            if phone_number:
                send_phone_updates()

            # Delay for 30 minutes
            time.sleep(1 * 10)
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error("Error in start_monitoring: %s", str(e))
```

above is the section its referring to

```
Error in set_email handler: start_monitoring() missing 1 required positional argument: 'message'
```

Comment: Looks like your error is occuring while you are calling this function and probably calling without `message`. The code you have posted is not quite relevant therefore.

Comment: @BijayRegmi can you message me on telegram